# Send mail using VB Script?

Tags: scripting, vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I have the following code to monitor a drive. Now I an getting Echo for each file creation or deletion event.

Is there and way to modify the WScript.Echo to send a mail notification?

```
strDrive = "c"
arrFolders(0) = strDrive & "\\\\"
 strComputer = "." 
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
 'Loop throught the array of folders setting up the monitor for Each 
 i = 0 
 For Each strFolder In arrFolders 
     'Create the event sink 
     strCommand = "Set EventSink" & i & " = WScript.CreateObject" & "(""WbemScripting.SWbemSink"", ""SINK" & i & "_"")" 
     ExecuteGlobal strCommand 
     'Setup Notification 
     strQuery = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent WITHIN 1 " & "WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile'" & " and TargetInstance.GroupComponent = " & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""" & strFolder & """'"
     strCommand = "objWMIservice.ExecNotificationQueryAsync EventSink" & i & ", strQuery"
     ExecuteGlobal strCommand 
     'Create the OnObjectReady Sub 
     strCommand = "Sub SINK" & i & "_OnObjectReady(objObject, " &  "objAsyncContext)" & VbCrLf & vbTab & "Wscript.Echo objObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent" & VbCrLf & "End Sub"
     WScript.Echo strCommand 
     ExecuteGlobal strCommand 
     i = i + 1 
 Next 
 WScript.Echo "Waiting for events..." 

 i = 0 
 While (True) 
     Wscript.Sleep(1000) 
 Wend
```

Instead of Echoing like below:

```
strCommand = "Sub SINK" & i & "_OnObjectReady(objObject, " &  "objAsyncContext)" & VbCrLf & vbTab & "Wscript.Echo objObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent" & VbCrLf & "End Sub"
```

I want to send a mail like this:

```
strCommand = "Sub SINK" & i & "_OnObjectReady(objObject, " &  "objAsyncContext)" & VbCrLf & vbTab & "

Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mailobj = outobj.CreateItem(0)
    With mailobj
        .To = toAddress
        .Subject = Subject
        .HTMLBody = strHTML
        .Send
    End With

" & VbCrLf & "End Sub"
```

Is it possible or is there an other way to do this..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what server do you use, but on Windows 2003 and 2008 e.g. you can use CDO object to create a email. You might use a smart host to send your email to.

Check this link: http://www.paulsadowski.com/wsh/cdo.htm

Also you can choose any free email component to create a email and use a smtp server to send your email. Or check this side where you can use a component including many examples how to do it: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-activex.asp.

** UPDATED **

This Script checks and send a email as you requestted:

```
strDrive = "d:"
Dim arrFolders(0) : arrFolders(0) = strDrive & "\\\\"
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2") 
'Loop throught the array of folders setting up the monitor for Each 
i = 0 
For Each strFolder In arrFolders 
  'Create the event sink 
  WScript.Echo "setup for folder: " & strFolder & vbLf
  strCommand = "Set EventSink" & i & " = WScript.CreateObject" & "(""WbemScripting.SWbemSink"", ""SINK" & i & "_"")" 
  ExecuteGlobal strCommand
  'Setup Notification 
  strQuery = "SELECT * " _
          & "FROM __InstanceOperationEvent " _
          & "WITHIN 1 " _
          & "WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile'" _
          & "  AND TargetInstance.GroupComponent = " & "'Win32_Directory.Name=""" & strFolder & """'"
  strCommand = "objWMIservice.ExecNotificationQueryAsync EventSink" & i & ", strQuery"
  ExecuteGlobal strCommand 
  'Create the OnObjectReady Sub 
  strCommand = "Sub SINK" & i & "_OnObjectReady(objObject, " &  "objAsyncContext)" & vbLf _
            & "  Wscript.Echo objObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent" & vbLf _
            & "  SendMail(objObject.TargetInstance.PartComponent)" & vbLf _
            & "End Sub"
  'WScript.Echo strCommand 
  ExecuteGlobal strCommand 
  i = i + 1 
Next 

WScript.Echo "Waiting for events..." 
i = 0 
While (True) 
  Wscript.Sleep(1000) 
Wend

Function SendMail(vBody)

  Dim oMail : Set oMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

  'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
  oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 
  oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "your.smtp.server"
  oMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
  oMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

  oMail.Subject = "Email Watch Info Message"
  oMail.From = "alert@yourdomain.net"
  oMail.To = "target@yourdomain.net"
  oMail.TextBody = vBody
  oMail.Send

End Function
```

Correct the settings in the send mail function and your are fine.

Comment: You need to install Outlook on your server if you want to create a instance of the program to use it. But what for? CDO can even do what you want.

Comment: @GokulNath Do you have access to an SMTP Relay Server or is the Email you want to send your message your Exchange account? I can write you a sample how to do it but tell me first please what environment you use.

Comment: @GokulNath Did it work as you want? Your bounty fall flat if you don't mark an answer :)

Comment: I didnt have time to check it out. Anyway, I'll accept this as an answer. Will try it later.

Comment: I run the script on my server and it sent me an email as expected. You just need to modify the settings and the body if you want to add more answers.

Comment: Thanks YvesR. I hope it works as expected for me. I'll try this out on weekend, and let you know the result. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Thanks much buddy. Tested today. Works as expected.

Comment: But it does not checks for InstanceModificationEvent. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, the VBSendMail DLL should be able to do what you want.